# Why didn't the Sovereign Class have folding warp nacelles?

Tags: star-trek, spaceship

In [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11860/how-do-voyagers-nacelles-rotation-solve-the-problems-stated-in-force-of-nature), the Intrepid Class' folding nacelles are explained as a feature designed to circumvent the problems stated in *TNG* 'Force of Nature'.  The Sovereign Class and Intrepid Class came into service around the same time.  The Intrepid class has these new folding nacelles, the Sovereign class seems not to (at least there is no mention of this on [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sovereign_class#Physical_arrangement) and I for one don't recall seeing the Sovereign class folding its nacelles).  *In-universe* then, **why didn't the Sovereign class get folding nacelles?**

---

More on the folding warp nacelles:

> According to the unpublished VOY Season 1 edition of the Star Trek:
>   Voyager Technical Manual by Rick Sternbach and Michael Okuda, (p. 12)
>   it was suggested that because of **this new folding wing-and-nacelle
>   configuration, warp fields might no longer have a negative impact on
>   habitable worlds as established in TNG: "Force of Nature"**. According
>   to Star Trek Encyclopedia, (3rd ed. p. 555) these nacelles did in fact
>   prevent damage to subspace.

([Source](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Variable_geometry_pylon))

Comment: Can't find it now but think that the sweeping nature of the pylon and nacelle configuration negated the need for it, in terms of subspace damage. Also was Voyager designed like that for mobility at sub light speed, not huge consideration for a capital ship

Comment: @user001 that would be an interesting explanation; I'd love to see an answer along those lines!  The folding nacelles although useful for sublight mobility though are still designed to circumvent the problems in 'Force of Nature' which holds true irrespective of the size of a ship; possibly even moreso for such a large ship which may need to engage at very high speeds which would only exacerbate the problems

Comment: My guess would be that voyager was a quick hack to produce something that works (e.g. create the "bad" warp field and fold it into a "good" one by moving the nacelles) and the sovereign did a more thorough fix of the problem by generating the "good" warp field right away.

Comment: I'm sure I've read that the Sovereign's overall shape (particularly its aerodynamic look) were to reduce/negate the damage to subspace. So Intrepid class ships did it one way, and Sovereign another.

Comment: The Nova class bears some superficial similarities with the Sovereign, especially the nacelles, so I like to think it was used to trial the Sovereign technology on a smaller, slower class before implementing it on what was to be the flagship class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Star Trek: A Call to Duty is a site which collects canon information and expands on it with some minimal degree of conjecture. It features the encyclopedias and technical manuals among its sources. It states:

"Computer-controlled rotation of the frame allows for manipulation of the manner in which the reactants meet, allowing for further control of the warp plasma into a "cleaner" power source.  Redesigned verterium cortenide components within each pair of warp field coils is then able to use the warp plasma to generate a more energy-efficient subspace field with less particle waste products and stresses that were found in older propulsion systems to damage subspace.  After the fleet-wide installation of this new variable warp geometry system, Starfleet was able to remove the so-called "Warp Speed Limit" of Warp 5, established in 2370 after the discovery of pollution by Dr. Serova in the Hekaras Corridor.  Pursuant to Starfleet Command Directive 12856.A, all starships traveling within Federation space are required to receive engine upgrades that prevent the further pollution of subspace by 2380."

So the Sovereign's propulsion system is 'cleaner' in the first place according to this source. As I said in my comment, I think it's clear that the Intrepid uses one method and the Sovereign another.